# Android BLE - BroadcastReceiver is not receiving BLE connection updates (ACTION_STATE_CHANGED, etc...)

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-broadcastreceiver

My onCreate() looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("BATTERY_LEVEL");
    myIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    myIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onBroadcastReceive, myIntentFilter);

More things....
}
```

And then I have this class below the main activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver onBroadcastReceive = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Main Activity", "Broadcast received");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("Action is", action);
        if (action != null) {
            switch (action) {
                case "BATTERY_LEVEL":
                    I can take it from here...
            }
        }
```

And I can take it from there.  I'm looking at the "Action is" printout to see the broadcasts coming in.

Later in my main app, I call a service that begins a Bluetooth connection in the foreground.  I know the connection is good.  First of all, this code in the service is properly run, and I get "gattCallback STATE_CONNECTED":

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            //status of 0 if operation succeeds
            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(600);
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    mGatt.close();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }

        }
    }
```

And second, the service is sending back Intents to main app (the action of "BATTERY_LEVEL" as defined in onCreate()".  These battery levels are coming from the Bluetooth device.  I get messages that say

```
I/Main Activity: Broadcast received
I/Action is: BATTERY_LEVEL
```

But I never get ACTION_STATE_CHANGED or ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED, even if I deliberately turn on and off Bluetooth.  Is it because it happens in another service?  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Have you defined ACTION_STATE_CHANGED or ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED. Also can you show us your `sendbroadcast(intent)` code.

Comment: Per the above comment I uploaded to source code for BLE Android Project onto github. Hopefully you can get get some ideas to resolve your issue. The link is https://github.com/mahengunawardena/ShapeTheWorld

Comment: Hm thanks, but where do you subscribe to get and then receive the Bluetooth Callbacks?

Comment: Take a look at BLE_Device file. `OnConnectionStateChange` there is a `broadcastUpdate(intentAction)` The intentAction is populated and then a `sendbroadcast(intent)` is executed. Check out github and revert back if you have more questions.

Comment: Note: This is my first BLE/Android App, I am still working on cleaning up the code. So any feedback is welcome.